# Make two c programs in one makefile

Tags: c, unix, gcc, makefile

Is it possible to make two files in a single makefile? Essentially a `program` and a `programtest`.  I have seen other answers, but their syntax went completely over my head.  Right now my Makefile only makes one of the programs, and I cant figure out how to have it make both

Would it be possible for someone to provide a template for how a Makefile would be structured to compile two programs?

Comment: Lets see what you have now?

Comment: The three answers I see below all have the defect that they don't list `all` as the first target in the makefile.  The first target is what is made when you run just `make` — it should normally build everything in the directory.  The makefiles also all have the defect of not using enough macros for the C compiler and its arguments.  Making sure that you use something like `${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} $*` allows you to juggle the compiler and the flags on the command line.  You can get more elaborate than that, but using macros is very important.

Answer (score 2):

```
    all: main test

    test: objects/Math.o objects/Stack.o objects/Queue.o objects/myUnitTesting.o objects/test.o
            gcc objects/test.o objects/Math.o objects/Stack.o objects/Queue.o objects/myUnitTesting -o test

    main: objects/Stack.o objects/Queue.o objects/Math.o objects/Point.o objects/main.o
            gcc objects/main.o objects/Stack.o objects/Queue.o objects/Point.o objects/Math.o -o main

    objects/test.o: test.c
            gcc -g -Wall -O -c -o objects/test.o test.c

    objects/main.o: main.c
            gcc -g -Wall -O -c -o objects/main.o main.c

    objects/myUnitTesting.o: cs/myUnitTesting.c
            gcc -g -Wall -O -c -o objects/myUnitTesting cs/myUnitTesting.c

    objects/Math.o: cs/Math.c
            gcc -g -Wall -O -c -o objects/Math.o cs/Math.c

    objects/Stack.o: cs/Stack.c
            gcc -g -Wall -O -c -o objects/Stack.o cs/Stack.c

    objects/Queue.o: cs/Queue.c
            gcc -g -Wall -O -c -o objects/Queue.o cs/Queue.c

    objects/Point.o: cs/Point.c
            gcc -g -Wall -O -c -o objects/Point.o cs/Point.c

    clean:
            rm -f objects/*o main
```

Then you only need to type:

```
    make all
```

and it is going to compile your `main.c` and `test.c` files

Comment: thank you! does than mean that "all" needs to be a phony target?

Comment: It will compile them both

Comment: It's conventional to list the `all` target first, so that when you type just `make`, everything is made.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiple exes in one makefile, here is sample for building 2, 
you need to do make all to build

```
prog1: prog1.o
    gcc prog1.o -o prog1 2>>compile.log 1>&2

prog2: prog2.o
    gcc prog2.o -o prog2 2>>compile.log 1>&2

all: prog1 prog2

.c.o:
    gcc -o $@ -c $*.c 2>>compile.log 1>&2
```

Comment: It's conventional to list the `all` target first, so that when you type just `make`, everything is made.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scenario where 2 targets are `main1` and `main2`.

```
TARGET1 = main1
TARGET2 = main2

$(TARGET1): main1.o
    gcc main1.o -o $@

$(TARGET2): main2.o
    gcc main2.o -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

run1: $(TARGET1)
    ./$(TARGET1)

run2: $(TARGET2)
    ./$(TARGET2)

all: $(TARGET1) $(TARGET2)
    ./$(TARGET1)
    ./$(TARGET2)
```

Remember that the indentation is a `<tab>` character, not space characters.

The following command will compile and run `main1` executable.

```
make run1
```

The following command will compile and run `main2` executable.

```
make run2
```

The following command will compile and run `main1` executable followed by `main2` executable.

```
make all
```

Comment: It's conventional to list the `all` target before the two separate targets.  That way, when you run just `make`, everything is made.  As it stands, running just `make` will only build `main1` and not `main2`.  It is also aconventional to have the `all` target run programs — it should only build them.  If you want to run them all, use a `runall` target (I suppose; I don't think there's an established name for that purpose).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
Here is a simpler version of the Makefile:

```
all: program programtest

program:
    gcc -o program program.c

programtest:
    gcc -o programtest programtest.c
```

Then you just have to type `make`:

```
$ make
gcc -o program program.c
gcc -o programtest programtest.c
```